# How to use Lateral joins with TypeORM for Postgres db?

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I have a postgres query with 5 joins which was taking more than 10 secs to execute. I re-wrote the query with lateral join concept and now it executes in less than 1 sec. I want to write that query in TypeORM and didn't find any ways to do it. Any help is appreciated.

This is the query that needs to be converted to TypeORM

```
FROM "institution" "i" 
INNER JOIN "financial_account" "fa" ON "fa"."institutionId"="i"."id" 
left join  (
    select h1.*
    from holding as h1
    inner join  (
        select cast(max(h3.holding_date) as DATE) holding_date,h3."accountId"
        From "holding" as h3
        group by h3."accountId"
    ) as h2 on h2."accountId" = h1."accountId" and h2."holding_date" = cast(h1."holding_date" as date)
) "h" on "h"."accountId" = "fa".id
LEFT JOIN "securities" "sec" ON "sec"."id"="h"."securityId"  
LEFT JOIN "symbol" "sym" ON "sym"."id"="sec"."symbolId" AND "sym"."trRIC"="sec"."symbolTrRIC" 
where "i".af_user_id='1234'
ORDER BY "h".institution_value desc;
```

Comment: please show what you have done so far

Comment: Added the query. Sorry I forgot to add it before.

Comment: please look at my answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67921184/how-to-use-left-join-lateral-in-typeorm/68194248#68194248
may be it can help you