# How to use LEFT JOIN LATERAL in typeorm?

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I want to use below query in TypeOrm but can't find a way to convert it to TypeOrm.

Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT * FROM blocked_times bt 
 LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT * FROM bookings bk WHERE bt."startTime" < bk."endTime"
 ) bk ON bk."clinicId" = bt."clinicId"
```

Comment: Have you looked through [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2074)? Looks like it's still lacking support.

Comment: Yes @Ryan I saw that

Answer (score 3):

I was fighting this issue for a couple of hours and found a hack

```
      queryBuilder.leftJoin("(SELECT 1)", "dummy", "TRUE LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM bookings bk WHERE bt.startTime < bk.endTime) bk ON bk.clinicId = bt.clinicId");
```

This is probably not the exact solution but should help you to get the general idea

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution.

```
const subQuery = `SELECT * FROM bookings bk WHERE bt."startTime" < bk."endTime"`;
queryBuilder.leftJoin((qb) => {
    qb.getQuery = () => `LATERAL (${subQuery})`;
    qb.setParameters({});
    return qb;
  },
  `bk`,
  `bk."clinicId" = bt."clinicId"`
)
```